# Mapreduce wordcount example is giving error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I used step by step guide as below.
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-hadoop-ubuntu

Then I tried to run mapreduce word count file on a text file.
The problem is that the program is not running and I am getting the AM Container for app and Exception from container-launch.

Is there any solution to this?

All nodes are working.

6544 Jps
3041 NameNode
3842 NodeManager
3219 DataNode
3494 SecondaryNameNode
3706 ResourceManager

Below is the yarn status output for my application.

```
doop@contactkarim-VirtualBox:~/hadoop-3.3.1$ yarn app -status application_1667981786519_0006
2022-11-09 11:35:22,184 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
2022-11-09 11:35:22,522 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2022-11-09 11:35:22,522 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
Application Report : 
    Application-Id : application_1667981786519_0006
    Application-Name : word count
    Application-Type : MAPREDUCE
    User : hdoop
    Queue : default
    Application Priority : 0
    Start-Time :  1667982679380
    Finish-Time : 1667982691120
    Progress : 0%
    State : FAILED
    Final-State : FAILED
    Tracking-URL : http://contactkm-VirtualBox:8088/cluster/app/application_1667981786519_0006
    RPC Port : -1
    AM Host : N/A
    Aggregate Resource Allocation : 20250 MB-seconds, 8 vcore-seconds
    Aggregate Resource Preempted : 0 MB-seconds, 0 vcore-seconds
    Log Aggregation Status : DISABLED
    Diagnostics : Application application_1667981786519_0006 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1667981786519_0006_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2022-11-09 11:31:31.113]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1667981786519_0006_02_000001
Exit code: 1

[2022-11-09 11:31:31.116]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.


[2022-11-09 11:31:31.116]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.


For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://contactkarim-VirtualBox:8088/cluster/app/application_1667981786519_0006 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
    Unmanaged Application : false
    Application Node Label Expression : <Not set>
    AM container Node Label Expression : <DEFAULT_PARTITION>
    TimeoutType : LIFETIME  ExpiryTime : UNLIMITED  RemainingTime : -1seconds
```

Thanks

I troubleshooted many things e.g. I checked the site settings, checked resources. Also, I went through the configurations multiple times. permissions etc are giving.

I am suspecting the java version here only.

Answer (score 0):

Linked blog says nothing about mapreduce, only cluster setup (which I always recommend following official Apache Hadoop site, not 3rd party blogs).

`No appenders could be found` means you're missing `log4j.properties` file submitted with your job - **See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.**

You won't be able to see the real runtime error/log output until you add that, e.g. if you've submitted your own jar built by maven/gradle to `src/main/resources`

Comment: Also, you don't need Hadoop installation to run mapreduce.  For example https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox